# $\zeta(2n)$ and amoebas

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Mikael Passare showed how to compute $\zeta(2)$ (*[How to compute $\sum 1/n^2$ by solving triangles](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701039)*) using the [amoeba](http://www.ams.org/notices/200208/what-is.pdf) of $1 + z + w = 0$.  Has this ever been generalized to higher zeta-values?  How might one compute $\zeta(2n)$ this way?

$$ \zeta(2) = \int_0^\infty \log(1 - e^{-x}) \, dx = \frac{1}{3}\int_{s + t < \pi} 1 \; ds \, dt $$

[image]

Comment: The left integral, as written, does not make sense: the integrand is undefined for $x>0$. For negative $x$, the integrand is negative.

Comment: you are correct $\int_0^\infty \log(1-e^{-x}) \; dx$

Comment: This essay may be of interest. It doesn't explicitly talk about amoebas but it does use the same curvilinear triangle area method and generalises the approach to a way to compute volumes of moduli spaces of abelian varieties: http://www.mfo.de/math-in-public/snapshots/files/special-values-of-zeta-functions-and-areas-of-triangles